# DC/DC split rail converter with coupled inductor

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inductor, step-down

I'm trying to build a *DC-DC* split-rail converter using circuit from [this article](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva369a/slva369a.pdf). My goal is to split *12..14V* input voltage into *+2.4V* and *-2.4V*. To do that, I choosed [LM1501AGR-ADJ](https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/138/DOC004138836.pdf) IC, calculated the needed inductance value (*15 uH*) and made the coupled inductor, then built the following circuit:

[image]

It works OK, but only when I apply a certain load. When the load is *1K* or more, *Vout-* is about *-11V*, and *Vout+* is *-0.2V* (input voltage is *12V*). Load resistance of *220R* or less makes *Vout-* equal to *-2.39V*, and *Vout+* to *2.36V*, which is just fine for my purposes.

I don't like the fact that circuit needs some "dummy" load to work correctly, because it means aditional power consumption. I'm gonna use battery as the power supply, so I whant it to consume as less power as possible. Besides, it looks like a very quick'n'dirty solution. Are there better ways to solve this problem?

To provide some additional information about the circuit, I tried to obtain the inductor's currents waveforms. To do that, I removed *C2* and *C3* and applied the load resistors *10R*, than measured the voltage waveform on them. Here is what I got:

[image: Primary coil]

Primary coil

[image: Primary coil - large scale]

Primary coil - large scale

[image: Secondary coil]

Secondary coil

By primary coil I mean the coil which is connected directly to IC.

Comment: Did you respect the dot notation on the coupled inductor in your design?

Comment: What Andy said, and for a "flybuck" design like this you'll need enough load on the primary output to be sure the inductor has enough energy to supply the secondary output.  (This is a non-synchronous converter.) You might want to check this out: http://www.ti.com/power-management/offline-isolated-dcdc-controllers-converters/flybuck-converters/overview.html

Comment: @Andy aka, yes, I did.

Comment: @John D, I'll try to apply some load as soon as possible and write back - maybe this will help.

Comment: @John D I tried to add some load (1K resistors for both outputs)  - unfortunately, it did not help... Maybe [this diodes](https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/641/DOC001641725.pdf) are not appropriate?

Comment: @msmirnov91 I'd look at the inductor currents if you can.  If not, take a step back and try to get the converter working as a simple buck with the second winding open.  Once that's working properly then connect it in the flybuck configuration and try again.  I suspect the transformer may be an issue.  Also, 1K load is very light.  Try drawing a few hundred mA.

Comment: @John D, You was right, thank you! With 220R load resistors circuit works fine. But just adding a dummy load doesn't look like a really good solution. Is there something better I can do with it? I updated my question again and added the inductor current waveforms - hope I measured them correctly.

Comment: You can switch to a synchronous converter like one of the TI parts in the link I sent that are intended for this type of operation.  Since the inductor current in those is continuous, they don't need a minimum load.

Comment: @John D Thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is just to summarise up the John D's explanations. The "primary coil" (which is connected directly to IC) must reserve enough energy for the "secondary coil". Since the inductor current is discontinious, it is possible only when the load consuming enough current is applied. Without it the circuit will not work correctly - in my case the output voltages without load were completey different from expected values. So, dummy load in my case is necessary. The other way is to use the circuit with continious current mode.